# Multiple Loops Meta Data

Tags: functions, loop, actions

I am now trying to figure out how to create the functions/ loops to pull my data from custom post types.

I have two post types(keys): And I need to pull the data from both to run my functions.

> `pods_product_grps`: (p_high, p_med, p_low, m_type, group_id)
>
> `product_variant`: (cogs, area, img_min, img_max, product_sku, grp_id)

Post are connected in **1 to many relationship** where `group_id==grp_id`

So when displaying both the archive of `pods_product_grps` and the single post that has a subloop of each `product_variant`  I need to display the calculated price based on a function I created.

The archive post only displays the lowest calculated price of the child variants.

Right now in my function, I have dummy variables to calculate the final price, but I need those to be populated automatically.

So I think I need to use this function:

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),$key, true);
```

but do I need to run that function for each key I need to define, or is there a way to make the key value an array and then return the values as individual variables.

```
//used in calculations-- dummy data
$p_high= 3.2; //get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),$key, true);
$p_med= 1.3;
$p_low =1.1;
$cogs= 11.53;
$img_count =3; //number of selected images between $img_min and $img_max
$img_cost= 10; //defined in settings page
$area= 40;
$client_lvl; //defined in user meta

//used in product display
$product_sku
```

I am not including the price calculation here, but it is in my other questions, and I can post it if needed.

I am assuming that after my function, I would then create an action hook for it to display in the content.

Would these variables extractions need to happen within the actual loop of say (`single-pods_product_grps.php`) or would including them in the function itself work and then call via the action?